# Python: counting number of iterations to achieve perfect shuffle?

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop

### **Question:**

If you split a deck of cards perfectly in half  and shuffle them with a perfect interleave, so that the first card of the half-deck on the left is always the top card, how many shuffles will it take until they return to their original order?

### My goal

I want to write a function that returns the number of shuffles needed to restore a deck to its original order. Example: For a deck of 8 cards, it takes 3 perfect shuffles to return to its original permutation. The first shuffle rearranges the cards to (1 5 2 6 3 7 4 8), the second shuffle rearranges the cards to (1 3 5 7 2 4 6 8), and the third shuffle restores the original order (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8). Therefore, shuffle(8) will return 3, shuffle(52) will return 8, and so on.

I was able to write a function for creating and shuffling the deck, but have been stumped from there:

```
def shuffle(deck_size):
    split_deck = deck_size//2
    first_half = list(range(1, (split_deck + 1)))
    second_half = list(range(split_deck +1, deck_size+1))
    shuffled_deck = [i for i in zip(first_half, second_half) for i in i]
    return shuffled_deck
```

Comment: This will never work if you are passing in an integer deck size instead of the deck itself

Comment: Thanks so much all for helping me understand Python's code better. Ioa Tzimas' answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a function that works with lists not integers. Try the following:

```
def shuffle(l):
    first_half =  l[:len(l)//2]
    second_half = l[len(l)//2:]
    return [i for i in zip(first_half, second_half) for i in i]
```

And now use this function repeatedly, until you will reach the original list again:

```
def tries(number):
    k=number//2*2
    c=0
    mylist=list(range(1, k+1))
    test=mylist.copy()
    while True:
        mylist=shuffle(mylist)
        c+=1
        if mylist==test:
            return c
```

For `number=8` it will give:

```
>>> tries(8)

3
```

Comment: Thanks, this was so helpful for helping me understanding the code. Can we do without 'k=number//2*2'?

Comment: No 'k=number//2*2' returns the number itself if number is even or the number before, if the number is odd. You must do it, with this or some other code, in order to be able to split the list into 2 equal parts

Answer (score 2):

Compare against a copy of the original deck after each shuffle.  Here also is a non-list comprehension, non-zip solution:

```
def shuffle(deck):
    # Assign even indices to the first half of the deck,
    # and odd indices to the last half of the deck.
    # Add one to deck to round up to handle odd card decks,
    # since even indices will get the odd card.
    half = (len(deck) + 1) // 2
    deck[::2], deck[1::2] = deck[:half], deck[half:]

deck = list(range(52))
goal = deck.copy()

count = 0
while True:
    shuffle(deck)
    count += 1
    if deck == goal:
        break

print(count)
```

Output:

```
8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def shuffle(deck):
    split_deck = len(deck)//2
    first_half = deck[:split_deck]
    second_half = deck[split_deck:]
    shuffled_deck = [i for i in zip(first_half, second_half) for i in i]
    return shuffled_deck


cards = 52
deck = [x for x in range(1,cards+1)]
c = 1
while True:
    deck = shuffle(deck)
    if deck == [x for x in range(1,cards+1)]:
        break
    else:
        c+=1

print(f'It took {c} shuffles to return the deck to its original orentation')
```